# Parse Query in order of creation in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to query my Parse database for a list of objects belonging to a User. I'm able to get all the objects, but I want them to appear in my tableView in the order they were created. I have tried using:

```
query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
```

but my table always comes out random. Is there a proper way I should be querying or is this something I should be handling client side?

Comment: can you share what you tried with a code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [PFQueryTableViewController](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html#//api/name/queryForTable) class to manage objects from table, override `queryForTable` method by returning PFQuery.